# After payment success, amount is not reflecting in sand box (adaptive parallel payment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, rubygems, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using this gem 'paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments'in ruby on rails. I get success after payment but when i saw my accounts in sandbox no one user get payments and also the merchant account is not debited. 
This is my response which I get from paypal after success

```
<PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments::DataTypes::PaymentDetailsResponse:0x00000007d3cfc8 @responseEnvelope=#<PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments::DataTypes::ResponseEnvelope:0x00000007d3cc80 @timestamp=Mon, 13 Jul 2015 00:04:03 -0700, @ack="Success", @correlationId="4a4043560f603", @build="17325060">, @cancelUrl="http://localhost:3000/payments/cancel", @currencyCode="USD", @ipnNotificationUrl="http://localhost:3000/payments/ipn_notify", @paymentInfoList=#<PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments::DataTypes::PaymentInfoList:0x00000007d33cc0 @paymentInfo=[#<PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments::DataTypes::PaymentInfo:0x00000007d33ba8 @receiver=#<PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments::DataTypes::Receiver:0x00000007d33ae0 @amount=160.0, @email="jaskaran@yopmail.com", @primary=false, @paymentType="SERVICE", @accountId="MNF7MDPJWJHJL">, @pendingRefund=false>, #<PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments::DataTypes::PaymentInfo:0x00000007d33388 @receiver=#<PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments::DataTypes::Receiver:0x00000007d33310 @amount=10.0, @email="user4paypal@yopmail.com", @primary=false, @paymentType="SERVICE", @accountId="HEPSP9YS5ZMPQ">, @pendingRefund=false>]>, @returnUrl="http://localhost:3000/payments/success", @status="CREATED", @payKey="AP-2G3459926X3244353", @actionType="PAY", @feesPayer="SENDER", @reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError=false, @sender=#<PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments::DataTypes::SenderIdentifier:0x00000007d325f0 @useCredentials=false>>
```

Here is status is created, I want to change it completed, Is need to call any api to do this again?

Answer (score 0):

Oh After searching 3 hours. I get the solution. :)
I had to add `senderEmail` parameter with the payer email. Thats it. In this way paypal let the transaction to be `COMPLETED`.